# Reading file attachments (Ex; .txt file) - Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, fs

Second time posting on StackOverflow so I apologize for any mistakes.
Please bear with me.

Same with the title; How do you read contents of a discord attachment let's say a `.txt` file and print the contents?

I have tried with `fs` but unfortunately failed and I have also searched the documentation but failed also.

[image]

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `fs` module for this as it only deals with local files. When you upload a file to the Discord server, it gets uploaded to a CDN and all you can do is grab the URL of this file from the [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) using the `url` property.

If you need to get a file from the web, you can fetch it from a URL using the built-in `https` module, or you can install one from npm, like the one I used below, [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

> To install `node-fetch`, run `npm i node-fetch` in your root folder.

Check out the working code below, it works fine with text files:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const client = new Client();

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  // get the file's URL
  const file = message.attachments.first()?.url;
  if (!file) return console.log('No attached file found');

  try {
    message.channel.send('Reading the file! Fetching data...');

    // fetch the file from the external URL
    const response = await fetch(file);

    // if there was an error send a message with the status
    if (!response.ok)
      return message.channel.send(
        'There was an error with fetching the file:',
        response.statusText,
      );

    // take the response stream and read it to completion
    const text = await response.text();

    if (text) {
      message.channel.send(`\`\`\`${text}\`\`\``);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder where this can be applied in practice?

Comment: I've got no idea, to be honest. Maybe @systemGene can tell us :)

Comment: It's a secret! :)