# Ask for file, read and send content to the channel using discord.js/javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to ask for a .txt file, read file and send the file content to the channel using a discord bot.

Description of intended behavior:

- User writes the command: !readfile
- Bot responds with message asking the user to drop/send the file in the
  chat
- Bot awaits for the file
- Bot reads the file content
- Sends the content back to the channel in a message

This is my most recent attempt at creating this command:

```
if (message.content === '!readfile') {

message.channel.send("Send your file please...");

 message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1}).then(msg => {
   const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
   let file = msg.attachments.first().file;
   fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
     msg.channel.send("Read the file! Fetching data...");
     msg.channel.send(data);
   });
 });
}
```

Comment: What problems/errors are you having? It’s hard to help if you don’t give us how exactly it doesn’t work.

Comment: @MrMythical it isn't an error, he/she wants to fetch the ".txt" or any file sent in a message.

Comment: also @noobami I don't feel there's any way to fetch the file from message except links and text or text format

Comment: Be 100% sure, that no user is going to abuse that. Sending files to a bot, and reading those, is one of the most dangerous things you can do with a discord bot. Your bot could crash, or in the worst case, your bot could get hacked. Maybe limit the function to only users with a certain role as a safety precaution.

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652628/reading-file-attachments-ex-txt-file-discord-js/67653732#67653732), you can't use the `fs` module to read the content of the attached files as it only deals with local files.

When you upload a file through Discord, it gets uploaded to a CDN. You can't grab the file itself (and there is no `file` property on the [MessageAttachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) either), all you can do is to grab the URL of the uploaded file using the [`url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url) property.

As you want to get a file from the web, you will need to fetch it by a URL. You can use the built-in `https` module, or you can install one from npm, like [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), etc.

I used `node-fetch` in my example and make sure you install it first by running `npm i node-fetch` in your root folder.

Check out the working code below, it works fine with text files:

```js
// on the top
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'readfile') {
    message.channel.send('Send your file please...');

    const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;

    try {
      const collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 });

      // get the file's URL
      const file = collected.first().attachments.first()?.url;
      if (!file) return console.log('No attached file found');

      // await the message, so we can later delete it
      const sent = await message.channel.send(
        'Reading the file! Fetching data...',
      );

      // fetch the file from the external URL
      const response = await fetch(file);

      // if there was an error send a message with the status
      if (!response.ok) {
        sent.delete();
        return message.channel.send(
          'There was an error fetching your file:',
          response.statusText,
        );
      }

      // take the response stream and read it to completion
      const text = await response.text();

      if (text) {
        sent.delete();
        return message.channel.send(`\`\`\`${text}\`\`\``);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return message.channel
        .send(`Oops, that's lame. There was an error...`)
        .then((sent) => setTimeout(() => sent.delete(), 2000));
    }
  }
});
```

Also, don't forget that [`awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) returns a collection of messages, even if the `max` option is set to 1, so you will need to grab the [`first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) one.

[image]